# Case when statement SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse, oracle-data-integrator

I am facing some difficulties for a Datawarehouse transformation task, I have some source columns which are coming in varchar format, data contained: Blanks, -, decimal numbers such as (1234.44).

Those columns in target are declared as number.

I am trying to treat that data with this code but I keep receiving invalid number error:

```
 CASE WHEN
        LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(column78input, '-', ' '))) is null then null 
    WHEN column78input IS NULL THEN 0
     else to_number(column78input)
END
```

In first when statement I am trying to check if there is - in source, it returns null when found, and if you find it then place it as null (replacing dashes with nulls in essence)

In second when statements I am trying to treat those blanks, I thought that they might cause the error

And finally in else statement I want to parse it from varchar to number to load in target table.

If someone has some kind of suggestion, please help!

Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Oracle Data Integrator, so I am mapping this code in it for transformation Source-Target. My source is a CSV, target as Oracle SQL

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Sounds like you might have other non-numeric values in that string besides the ones you're handling.

Comment: Consider what the code above would do when the value of column78input is `'banana'`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, basically yes. 
Oracle Data Integrator appends it as SQL code for a particular column.

Comment: @scaisEdge  When it is a number such as 12312.412 place it as number (but parse it)
when it is a - place it as 0
when it is blank place it as 0

Comment: If you want to replace `-` with zero then you need to do it in the first branch. CASE() is a switch, only one branch is activated per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
CASE
    WHEN INSTR(column78input, '-') > 0 OR column78input IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(column78input, ' '))
END
```

INSTR returns the first position of a character in a string. So if there is no dash, it would return 0. A value greater than 0 means there is at least one dash in the string.

Here are a few mistakes in your code :

- A case when statement will exit when a condition is met. So you can remove the dash in the first condition and expect it to continue to process your string in the next condition. In your code if a string had a dash, the result would be null.
- LENGTH function returns the number of characters in a string. It will return a null value only if the string is null. So it's easier to directly write `column78input IS NULL`
- You current first condition is basically this : "*After replacing the dash by a space and removing all the leading/trailing spaces, if the string is null then*". Because you are replacing the dashes in the string, you can't check if there is an occurrence or not.